# Swift versus Swift parallel scripting language

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone please elaborate if Apple's Swift programming language is related to the Swift parallel scripting language, and if yes, how ?

Looking at the websites, the two seem unrelated, but still wanted to make sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than the name, the swift parallel scripting language is not even remotely related to the Apple's swift programming language.